# how to check post image by id in php

Tags: php, html

I have 3 inputs :

**1.** application name

**2.** Background photo

**3.** logo photo

After I got help from @mith. The code is great. Images always go into correct folder. I adapt the code to change image's name after submit it into folder. But i don't know what wrong with this condition

```
$fieldname = ($key == 'image[]') ? 'image' : 'logo';
$filename  = $applicationName . '_' . $fieldname . '.' . 
          pathinfo($upload["tmp_name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

`$filename` always be logo. I don't know why the condition always false.
So, 2 images always named applicationName_logo. please help me find out.

**HTML form :**

```html
<form action="yong.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>App name</h3>
    <input type="text" id="applicationName" name="applicationName">
    <h3>Background image</h3>
    <input type="file" id="image" name="image[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
    <h3>Logo image</h3>
    <input type="file" id="logo" name="logo[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP code :

```
    <?php
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 5000*100; //100 kb
$path = "home_dir/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
// Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files

$applicationName = $_POST['applicationName'];
$sql_field_list  = ['applicationName'];
$sql_value_list  = [$applicationName];

foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $f => $name) {
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
        echo "Skip file if any error found";
    }
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'][$f] == 0) {
        if ($_FILES['image']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
            echo "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            echo "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files
            $tmp_name  = $upload["tmp_name"];
            $parts     = explode('/', $upload['tmp_name']);
            $tmpName   = array_pop($parts);
            $fieldname = ($key == 'image[]') ? 'image' : 'logo';
            $filename  = $applicationName . '_' . $fieldname . '.' . pathinfo($upload["tmp_name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        }

            //if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$filename.png))
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.'applicationName_bg/'.$filename.png))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            $message[] = "$name is uploaded";
            echo "$filename is uploaded";

    }
}

foreach ($_FILES['logo']['name'] as $f => $name) {
    if ($_FILES['logo']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
        echo "Skip file if any error found";
    }
    if ($_FILES['logo']['error'][$f] == 0) {
        if ($_FILES['logo']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
            echo "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            echo "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files
            $tmp_name  = $upload["tmp_name"];
            $parts     = explode('/', $upload['tmp_name']);
            $tmpName   = array_pop($parts);
            $fieldname = ($key == 'image[]') ? 'image' : 'logo';
            $filename  = $applicationName . '_' . $fieldname . '.' . pathinfo($upload["tmp_name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        }

            //if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$filename.png))
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.'applicationName_logo/'.$filename.png))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            $message[] = "$name is uploaded";
            echo "$filename is uploaded";

    }
}
}
```

Comment: use `files['image'][]`  and `files['logo'][]` and automatically it will be differentiated. You can check it by printing out `$_FILES` in your php code. It will give you multi-dimensional array with two main keys which is `image` and `logo`

Comment: php does not identifies the `id` it knows the `name`.

Comment: Differentiate the input fields using keys.  PHP can not read HTML ID attribute by default. The best way to get differentiate the INPUT FILE is to seprate them using key.
e.g <input type="file" name="logo[]" multiple="multiple"
                                                  accept="image/*">

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to save logo and image files separately:

HTML:

```
<form action="yong.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h3>App name</h3>
  <input type="text" id="applicationName" name="applicationName">
  <h3>Background image</h3>
  <input type="file" id="image" name="image[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
  <h3>Logo image</h3>
  <input type="file" id="logo" name="logo[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 5000*100; //100 kb
$path = "home_dir/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
// Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $f => $name) {
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
        echo "Skip file if any error found";
    }
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'][$f] == 0) {
        if ($_FILES['image']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
            echo "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            echo "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.'applicationName_bg/'.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            $message[] = "$name is uploaded";
            echo "$name is uploaded";
        }
    }
}

foreach ($_FILES['logo']['name'] as $f => $name) {
    if ($_FILES['logo']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
        echo "Skip file if any error found";
    }
    if ($_FILES['logo']['error'][$f] == 0) {
        if ($_FILES['logo']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
            echo "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            echo "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.'applicationName_logo/'.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            $message[] = "$name is uploaded";
            echo "$name is uploaded";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: create folders applicationName_logo and applicationName_bg inside home_dir and try above answer. I have changed upload path in my code. @Splicee

Comment: I have got some problem.
but I cannot ask you in comment box because it's too long. Please reread it again at above

@mith